# Can I use multiple for loop in a loop?

Tags: java, spring, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to generate the following report:

```
| Place Name   | City or Town?   | Country   |
----------------------------------------------
| Place A      | City            | England   |
| Place B      | City            | England   |
| Place X      | Town            | England   |
| Place Y      | Town            | England   |
| Place Q      | City            | Germany   |
| Place P      | City            | Germany   |
| Place T      | Town            | Germany   |
| Place W      | Town            | Germany   |
```

While generating this report, I pass `countryList` that has a `cityList` for each country as shown below:

```
for(Country country : countryList)
{
    for(City city : country.getCityList())
    {
        generateRow(country, city);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, there is also another (separate) list that keeps towns and I need to generate town rows after each city as shown above. In this scene I think the only way is to use a second for loop after the city loop as shown below, but as I have never used such kind of multiple loop in a loop (I use cascade / nested many times, but not like this), I would like to be clarified if there is a better option for this scenario.

```
for(Country country : countryList)
{
    for(City city : country.getCityList())
    {
        generateRow(country, city);
    }

    // townList is a separate list, not in country or city list
    for(Town town : townList()) 
    {
        generateRowForTown(town);
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach for that?

Comment: That is fine, although I don't see how you get the just the towns for the current country from your example.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this, but your way is perfectly fine. Note that the question is off-topic for StackOverflow because there is no specific problem/error, questions like this are best asked over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. On the other hand, it is not a specific problem, this approach can also be used by someone else and your answers will also be useful for them.

Comment: You said `I need to generate town rows after each city` but you are not generating after each city. You are placing towns after all cities in that country. Also, how do you get list of towns for given country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine. That being said, you could make `Town` and `City` both implement some `Liveable` or `RowGenerator` interface or super class (name depends on what you will be putting in there) with a `generateRow()` method in there. That would allow you to store both `Town` and `City` instances in a single `List<RowGenerator>` field or variable, allowing you to handle them both in a single loop. Performance wise, this does not change anything noticeable, but this is an option to consider for such cases might you encounter them in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There are 2 issues, could you pls have a look at? >>>

Comment: **1.** As the `townList` contains all of the towns for all countries, it generates row from the first town for each City. I can use a counter to keep the last value maybe, but is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: **2.** Could you please post example code of your explanations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.